# Javascript to get the last paragraph text in HTML block

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

This is fairly simple I'm sure but I'm having some trouble with it. I'm trying to use Sharepoint 2013 Client Side Rendering (CSR) to format a sharepoint field containing a long block of text to only show the last paragraph block (the idea is to have a "last update status" for tasks that reports whatever the last line of entry was).

So, given this block of html as an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ExternalClass473CC6A801594594826FDFA0BFAD6B1E">
      <p>​</p>
      <p style="margin:0in;font-family:calibri;font-size:14pt;color:#0070c0;">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Current Status</span>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">: Pending</span>
      </p>
      <p style="margin:0in;font-family:calibri;font-size:12pt;">Some update</p>
      <p style="margin:0in;font-family:calibri;font-size:12pt;">Some Update 2</p>
      <p style="margin:0in;font-family:calibri;font-size:12pt;">THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO GET
      <br /></p>
      <p>
        <br />
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I use either regex or a javascript html parser to set a variable to contain "THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO GET"?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you want that text in a variable or to be the only one being displayed?

Comment: I'm using this as a general template: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-93e7077d

But instead of only rendering the first bit of text as a summary, I want the last line of text instead.

Comment: Should mention I'm not much of a javascript user, I'm more backend stuff and know Powershell, .NET, XML, HTML, and CSS well, but haven't had to use a lot of javascript, and I just have this one thing I need to sort out for a new sharepoint task list :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By **"the last paragraph block"** do you mean the last "p" element? if so why not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    target = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[-1];
    content = target.innerText || target.textContent;
  };
</script>
```

In jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    target = $("p").last();
    content = target.html();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closest to what I actually did. I found a way without using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You could forgo using JS altogether and do this using CSS. Stick this into your `<head>`.

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
  display: none; /* This hides all p tags */
}
p:last-child {
  display: inline; /* This will show the last p tag */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some funky regex magic

```
document
// Get the parent node
.querySelector('.ExternalClass473CC6A801594594826FDFA0BFAD6B1E') 
// Get the contents as text
.textContent
// Look for any character, then match all the way until there's a linebreak or its the end of the string. 
.match(/\w.+(\n|$)/g)
// Get the last matching item
.slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textYouWantToGet = document.querySelector('p:last-child').innerText
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was fairly that easy and had just considered that, but, I just don't know if "document" will work with sharepoint jsLink or not. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Found last-child won't work because it gets the last child of each parent element, not the last element period which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy if the `<p>` tag you wanted to assign to a variable had something like an id so JavaScript can identify it.

If you did that you could simply do : `var text = document.querySelector("#id").value`

Alternatively if this is not an option, you would have to seek it out among the `<p>` tags yourself.

something like : `var pTags = document.getElementByTagName("p");
               var theTextIwant = "";
               for(var i = 0; i < Ptags.length; i++){if(pTags[i] == "text i want; 
                   theTextIwant = pTags[i];
                )}`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I spent the last day on this, but it looks like the simplest and most foolproof thing to do was this:

```
var bodyElements = doc.querySelectorAll("p");

//Find the last non-empty element
//TODO: Go back and try another element if all elements of the specified type are empty
var i = bodyElements.length;
var newBodyValue = "";
while (!(/\S/).test(newBodyValue) || i < 0) {
    i--;
    try {
        newBodyValue = bodyElements[i].innerText;
        if (!newBodyValue) {continue;}
    } catch (err) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

last-child selector didn't work because I need the last non-empty element *period*, not just the last per hierarchy. I later learned I could have easily used JQuery for this but I was trying to keep it pure to keep Sharepoint overhead minimal.

I had to add a bunch of extra stuff but here's the final CSR JSLink result. It takes a standard Sharepoint task list and modifies the description field so that it only shows whatever the last line entered was. This is useful for a particular summary view where I want the information as compact as possible.

https://gist.github.com/JustinGrote/4fd3b5e7bf0420c283a9

Thanks to all for your suggestions.

I know I probably didn't follow best practices on a lot of stuff, but I have only been using Javascript for about 10 hours total, so sue me :)